# MySQL some columns Distinct

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works well.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT city,region1,region2 from static_geo_world where country='AU' AND
 (city LIKE '%geel%' OR region1 LIKE '%geel%' OR region2 LIKE '%geel%' OR region3 LIKE '%geel%' OR zip LIKE 'geel%') ORDER BY city;
```

I need to also extract a column named 'id' but this messes up the DISTINCT as each ID is different.

How can I get the same UNIQUE set of records as above but also get the 'id' for each record?
Note: sometimes I can return a few thousand records so a query for each record isn't possible.

Any ideas would be very welcome...

Example:

Table might have the follow

```
 ID Country zip  region1        region2  region3 City
 1  AU      3323 geelong        victoria         Geelong
 2  AU      3324 geelong        victoria         Geelong
 3  AU      3325 Geelong North  victoria         Geelong
```

I want to get the distinct set of city, region1 and region2 as there can be duplicates on different post codes. This the current query does. But I also want to get the ID as this is what I will put into the DB for the selected record as a reference.

Results Wanted:

I wanted to be able to get the unique 'city,region1,region2 being

```
 geelong geelong victoria
 geelong geelong north victoria
```

And the initial query gets these results

But I also wanted to know the ID for the records that have been returned. This ID I will use in the user profile (stored in DB). eg:

```
 1 geelong geelong victoria
 3 geelong geelong north victoria
```

Hope this explains it better.
Just need to include the returned Distinct records ID as well.

Comment: Your question states two irreconcilable objectives.  You want to collapse multiple records with the same values in city,region1,region2, but then want all the distinct IDs for those records.  I suggest you write out some examples of the input and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: OK, you've added the input data.  NOW, show what resultset you want from this query, including the ID column.

Comment: Why is the returned ID 1 and not 2?

Comment: maybe this is the limitation of DISTINIC. Is there a different way to do the query I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you seem to be asking for:

Input data:

```
ID  City   Region1  Region2
--- ------ -------- --------
 1  geel1  geel2    geel3
 2  geel1  geel2    geel3
 3  geel4  geel5    geel6
 4  geel1  geel2    geel3
```

The query `select distinct city,region1,region2` returns

```
City   Region1  Region2
------ -------- --------
geel1  geel2    geel3
geel4  geel5    geel6
```

Having removed duplicate rows, there is no longer a unique ID for a row.  You state

> How can I get the same UNIQUE set of records as above but also get the 'id' for each record

But for the first returned row there are three possible IDs and it makes no sense to ask for "the 'id' for each record".

EDIT

If you just want, say, the lowest ID, you could do this:

```
select min(id),city,region1,region2 from ... where ... group by city,region1,region2
```

Comment: the data is being passed from server back to browser. When the user selects one I wanted to take the ID and put this into the user profile in the DB. The ID would be my reference. I hear what your saying.

Comment: WHICH ID would you want returned for the first query result row above? 1, 2 or 4?

Comment: actually it doesn't matter so long as is consistently the same each time. I have a Table with over 6mil locations and so long as the query  gives the same results it will work. There for in your case I would have though 1 and 3 ID's only - being the first found.

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked this but wouldn't this work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (city,region1,region2), ID from static_geo_world where country='AU' AND
 (city LIKE '%geel%' OR region1 LIKE '%geel%' OR region2 LIKE '%geel%' OR region3 LIKE '%geel%' OR zip LIKE 'geel%') ORDER BY city;
```

Hope this works!

Comment: I get a error as soon as I put the DISTINCT columns in (brackets).

Comment: If you are using mysql5 or higher this probably won't work. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: thats ok... ya doesn't work... thanks for your thoughts .. appreciated.

Comment: I've added a way to do this to my answer.  HOWEVER, it is bad design to do this.  Maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish in conceptual terms we can point you in a better direction.

Comment: sure. I have a DB with over 6million locations in it. There are duplicates in the DB - eg: cities with 2 to 50 different postcodes but its the same city. I don't want to change the DB as the search also works on postcode. Therefore I just want to unique set of locations which can be achieved with DISTINIC. I think need to record the users selection in their Profile and wanted to link this to an ID. This is why I wanted an ID. let me know if I should explain more

Comment: the group by works perfectly and there is no speed loss (something I'm just keeping an eye on). thankyou so much. Can I ask my its bad design? I would like to understand this aspect better. thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Use group by instead

```
SELECT id , city,region1,region2 from static_geo_world where country='AU' AND
(city LIKE '%geel%' OR region1 LIKE '%geel%' OR region2 LIKE '%geel%' OR region3 LIKE     '%geel%' OR zip LIKE 'geel%') ORDER BY city group by city;
```

This will return what you need. But from the db records it will always choose the first record found means if city = 'A' and with this city there are many records it will choose the first record found and will return its id